# Get git to tell me where the offending whitespace is?

Tags: git, automation, whitespace, verbosity

During a rebase of some git branch of mine, I get a warning saying:

```
/path/to/repo/.git/rebase-apply/patch:21: trailing whitespace.
some text in a file here
```

Now, I can go grepping for that string, but - is there a way to make git tell me in which file (and maybe at which line number) it found the offending trailing whitespace?

Comment: The whitespace errors come from the patch (What you're trying to rebase on top of). You probably still have the patch in your repo (`/path/to/repo/.git/rebase-apply/patch`) that you can look at to know which file it was. Do you also want to ensure that you're not committing trailing whitespace?

Comment: "Do you also want to ensure that you're not committing trailing whitespace?" <- Maybe... if I say yes, would this help me?

Comment: Not for your original question, no. But I wasn't sure if you thought you were the offender or not.

Comment: @zrrbite: I am :-(

Comment: For now you can probably check the patch file. But It would probably be a good idea to push a strategy in your team to remove trailing whitespaces upon commit. I've seen a number of posts in here on that topic.